# Chart.CopyPicture vs Chart.Copy C# - Copy Paste large amount of excel charts to powerpoint

Tags: c#, excel

Problem: I am trying to copy 1000's of charts from excel and paste in powerpoint using C# and Interop. My problem is that sporadically sometimes charts do not get pasted.

How i solved it:
I was using chartobj.Copy() to copy and then PasteSpecial fucntion. With this, there were a lot of charts that were missed during the process of copy and paste so i changed this to use CopyPicture and Paste instead and it is now working.

My Question: What is the different between CopyPitcture and Copy?  Any explanation as to why this is working vs Copy ? Similarly difference between Paste and PasteSpecial and why Paste works consistently.

Thanks